# How to solve this inheritance problem

Tags: c#, design, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class StaticFileController<File, QueryData> : AsyncController
{
     private string _resourceName;

     public StaticFileController(string resourceName)
     {
          _resourceName = resourceName;
     }

     //This method receives _resourceName
     protected virtual void DoSomething(string resource)
     {
         //...
     }
}

public class ScriptController : StaticFileController<FileEntity, ScriptQueryData>
{
     public ScriptController : base("scripts") { }
}

public class StyleController : StaticFileController<FileEntity, StyleQueryData>
{
     public StyleController : base("styles") { }
}
```

Now, let's suppose I have this class:

```
public class ScriptBundleController : ScriptController
{
     protected override void DoSomething(string resource)
     {
         // Use resource name and do something (~50 lines of code)
     }
}
```

If I want to create a similar class for `StyleController`, I would have to create a new class (**with the exact same implementation**):

```
public class StyleBundleController : StyleController
{
     protected override void DoSomething(string resource)
     {
         // Use resource name and do something (~50 lines of code)
     }
}
```

This troubles me because it seems I am duplicating code, which will give me problems in the future.

How can I solve this problem? I want to have my implementation written only in one place. I understand that two classes would likely be needed, such as `ScriptBundleController` and `StyleBundleController` but I want the `DoSomething()` method to be centralized in just one class.

Comment: Why override the ResourceName when you can pass it in?

Comment: @Telastyn You mean I should pass it as an argument to `DoSomething()`?

Comment: Or as a constructor parameter to `StaticFileController`.

Comment: @Telastyn I have applied your suggestion, but the problem persists. (See edit)

Comment: you don't need it _both_ as a function parameter and a constructor parameter... Also, if `DoSomething` is common to all `StaticFileController`s then, push the code there. If it is not, then some intermediary type between `StaticFileController` and `Script/Style-Controller`.

Still, this is smelly overuse of inheritance.

Comment: You haven't stated why you feel you need an inheritance hierarchy that is this deep.

Comment: @Telastyn `ScriptsController` and `StylesController` both define the resource name, which will be used to retrieve a specific file. I also have a `ScriptBundleController`, which will override a method so I can fetch multiple files in one single request. I want `ScriptBundleController` to take advantage of some minimization logic inside `ScriptController`, so `ScriptBundleController` **must** extend from `ScripController`. However, I cannot add a base class for the logic in  `ScriptBundleController`, as only one inheritance is allowed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See comment above. I should also note that I would be able to call `ScriptController` on its own. However, if the client intends to call `ScriptBundleController`, I want `ScriptController` logic to be executed too.

Comment: What distinguishes ScriptController from StyleController, other than the fact that they have the same non-descript method?  Why don't you just put the common methods in the one base class?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `ScriptController` should use `scripts` as resource name, and `StyleController` should use `styles` as resource name. That's basically the only difference, and the need for two different classes.

Comment: What prevents you from putting the common method into the abstract base class?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't want it to be on the base class, because it does not belong there. For example, the method minifies my script / style. The logic is the same in both `ScriptController` and `StyleController`. But I also have an `ImageController` which extends from `StaticFileController`. I don't want `ImageController` to have minification logic.

Comment: Your alternative is to have yet another class.  Why not just put a `static` `Minify()`method in the abstract class, and let whatever wants to use it use it?  By making it `static`, it won't be a part of the instantiated class's public API.  Make sure it's a *pure* method; you put something in, you get something out, and no state is modified.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get a useful answer without more detail/specifics about your situation. This is a question about design, so it's extremely difficult to answer without knowing *what* it is you're trying to design. What does `DoSomething` do? What are those generic parameters for? Do `Script` and `Style` controllers do something different other than passing a different argument to the base constructor? What's a bundle controller for?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of basing your inheritance on methods which are common in this case it may make more sense to have an outside helper class which contains methods your Controllers can use:

```
public class FileHelper
{
    public YourReturnTypeIfAny Minify(YourParameters params)
    {
        // your minify logic
    }
}
```

Then you can call `Minify()` from your `DoSomething()` methods in your `StaticFileControllers`

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is you cant do exactly this. If you think about it you would be effectively exposing private variables.

say we can do something like :

```
 public class ScriptBundleController : ScriptController
    {
        protected override void DoSomething(string resource)
        {
            ((BundleController<FileEntity, ScriptQueryData>)this).DoSomething(resource);
        }
    }
```

re casting the object to something outside its inheritance chain in order to give our apply our new DoSomething Function to the current object.

But DoSomething in BundleController can access the private variables of BundleController and hence ScriptBundleController and change them, which is exactly what setting them to private is supposed to stop!

you can do it if you change the inheritance chain and insert BundleController between your script/style controllers and the base class, passing the generic types down. But this isn't quite the same functionality, because DoSomething could be overridden in the script/style controllers .

eg.

```
public class StyleController : BundleController<FileEntity, StyleQueryData>
{
     public StyleController() : base("styles") { }
}

public class BundleController<T1, T2> : StaticFileController<T1, T2>
{
    public BundleController(string resourceName)
        : base(resourceName)
    { }

    protected override void DoSomething(string resource)
    {
        // Use resource name and do something (~50 lines of code)
    }
}
```